# How to show $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}x^{-1} dx = \infty$

Tags: calculus, integration

How do we obtain result

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}x^{-1} \;\mathrm dx = \infty$$

Answer (score 5):

How about $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x} x^{-1} \, dx \ge e^{-1} \int_0^1 x^{-1} \, dx = \infty?$$

Comment: It's a great hint, but the OP might benefit from a little more detailed analysis.

Comment: The OP is free to ask for such in a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Notice, 
Laplace transform of a function divided by $t$ is given as $$L\left[\frac{f(t)}{t}\right]=\int_{s}^{\infty}L[f(t)]ds$$

Now, using Laplace transform as follows $$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}x^{-1}dx$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}\frac{1}{x}dx$$
$$=L\left[\frac{1}{t}\right]_{s=1}$$
$$=\int_{s=1}^{\infty} L\left[1\right] ds$$
$$=\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{s} ds$$
$$=[\ln |s|]_{1}^{\infty}$$ $$=\lim_{s\to \infty}\ln |s|-\ln|1|$$
$$=\lim_{s\to \infty}\ln |s|=\infty$$

Comment: First of all, $\frac 1 x$ does not have a Laplace transform. Second, what results do you use when you write $L[\frac 1 t] _{s=1} = \int \limits _{s=1} ^\infty L[1] \Bbb d s =  \int \limits _1 ^\infty \frac 1 s \Bbb d s$? This seems to be total nonsense.

Comment: @Alex M  I think so too. and Harish Please write more detail. thank a lot.

Comment: @Alex M. Perhaps you do not know the division formula.    Note that Laplace transform of a function divided by $t$ is given as $$L\left[\frac{f(t)}{t}\right]=\int_{s}^{\infty}L[f(t)]ds$$hence $L\left[\frac{1}{t}\right]=\int_{s}^{\infty}L[1]ds=\int_{s}^{\infty}\frac{1}{s}ds=(\ln |s|)_{s}^{\infty}$

Comment: You use $s$ both as a lower endpoint, and as an integration variable, maybe you want to correct this. With the explanation you have just given, I can understand your computation now, but it is still based on the mistaken assumption that $\frac 1 x$ has a Laplace transform. It doesn't. In fact, the OP's question could even be reformulated as: *"show that $\frac 1 x$ is not Laplace transformable"*.

Comment: http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/c2003/LaplaceMultDivMod.html :  condition  $\displaystyle \lim_{t \to 0^+}\frac{f(t)}{t}$ exists.